# Show that assumptions of theorem hold, determine the solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the initial value problem

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
y'(t)=\sqrt{|y|}, 0 \leq t \leq 2\\ 
y(0)=1
\end{matrix}\right. \tag 1$$

Show that for this problem the assumptions of the following theorem hold:

"Let $c>0$ and $f \in C([a,b] \times [y_0-c, y_0+c])$. If $f$ satisfies at $[a,b] \times [y_0-c, y_0+c])$ the Lipschitz condition in respect to $y$, uniformly in respect of $t$, that means that:

$$\exists L \geq 0: \forall t \in [a,b] \ \forall y_1, y_2 \in [y_0-c,y_0+c]: \\ |f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)| \leq L |y_1-y_2|$$

then the initial value problem $\left\{\begin{matrix}
y'(t)=f(t,y(t)) &, a \leq t \leq b \\ 
y(a)=y_0 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$ is solved uniquely at least at the interval $[a,b']$ where with $A=\max_{a \leq t \leq b, y_0-c \leq y \leq y_0+c} |f(t,y)|$ we have that $b'=\min \{ b, a+ \frac{c}{A}\}$. "

for appropriate $c$ and $L$.
Determine the solution $y$ with the method of seperation of variables.

I tried the following:

$$f(t)=\sqrt{|y|}$$

$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}(t, y(t))=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{|y|}} \leq M \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2M} \leq \sqrt{|y|} \Rightarrow y \geq \frac{1}{4M}$$

$$y(0)-c=1-c=\frac{1}{4M} \Rightarrow c=1-\frac{1}{4M}$$

Then $(1)$ is solved uniquely, at least at the interval $[0,b']$ where $A=\max_{0 \leq t \leq 2, \frac{1}{4M} \leq y \leq 2-\frac{1}{4M}} |\sqrt{|y|}|=\sqrt{2-\frac{1}{4M}}$

$$b'=\min \{ 2, \frac{1-\frac{1}{4M}}{\sqrt{2-\frac{1}{4M}}}\}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{4M}}{\sqrt{2-\frac{1}{4M}}}$$

$$L=M$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\sqrt{|y|} \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{2\sqrt{y}}=\frac{dt}{2} \Rightarrow \sqrt{y}=\frac{1}{2}t+c$$

$$y(0)=1 \Rightarrow c=1$$

So:

$$\sqrt{y}=\frac{1}{2}t+1 \Rightarrow y=\left(  \frac{1}{2}t+1\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}t^2+t+1$$

Is it right or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dt} = \sqrt{|y|}$$ fails the uniquness criteria only on the axis $y = 0.$  if you have initial values away from $0$ like $y(0) = 1,$ then the solution $$y = (1+ \frac t2)^2, -2 \le t < \infty.$$ at $t = -2,$ the uniquness fails and you have another solution $y = 0$ identically.

Comment: We have that:

$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}(t,y(t))=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y}} $$

The latter goes to $+\infty$ if $y \to 0$ but it goes to a real number if $y$ goes anywhere else, right?
$$$$
If so, then it has to be $y_0-c>0$ or $y_0-c<0$, right?
$$$$
So could we suppose $y_0-c>0 \Rightarrow 1-c>0 \Rightarrow c<1$ and take a random $c$, for example $c=\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: in a box around the initial value $t = 0, y = 1,$ the right hand side is just $\sqrt y $ which satisfies the uniqueness requirement. you start there and continue you solution in both directions. when the $y$ hits $0$ you have the problem that rhs is not lipschitz. in this case you have the identically zero solution in addition to the one you continued backwards from $t = 0$  at $t = -2$. you wont be able to continue to the left of $t = -2$ in a unique way.

Comment: abel Could you explain me further how we can show that for the problem we are looking at the assumptions of the theorem hold? :/

Comment: @evinda,  does $f(t,y) = \sqrt y, y > 0$ satisfy the uniquness requirements for $\frac{dy}{dt} = f(t,y)?$

Comment: Doesn't it satisfy  the uniquness requirements for any interval that does not contain $0$ , abel?

Comment: @evinda, your initial value problem satisfies the uniqueness requirement on $(-2, \infty) \times (0, \infty)$

Comment: In order to find the intervals at which the  initial value problem satisfies the uniqueness requirement, aren't we looking for the $y$s for which $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}(t,y)$ goes to a real number? Or am I wrong?

Comment: you are looking for a region in the $(t,y)$ plane where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is bounded. you are not taking any limits here.

Comment: $$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y}} \leq M \Rightarrow \sqrt{y} \geq \frac{1}{2M} \Rightarrow y \geq \frac{1}{4M^2}$$
How can we find like that the restrictions?

Comment: @evinda, that is correct. as long as $|y| > \frac{1}{4M^2}$ the $|f_y| < M$ condition is satisfied.  as long as you stay away from $y = 0,$ you have uniqueness.

Comment: You mean $|f_y| \leq M$ ?